# Generate Google ReCaptcha from a local website

Tags: javascript, python, http-post, python-requests, recaptcha

I'm crawling a website using the python requests module. A form on this website requires to solve a ReCaptcha. I've managed to recreate this ReCaptcha on a local website with the same site-key. If I solve the ReCaptcha on my local website and get the 'g-captcha-response' key, would I be able to post this key to the original website? If so, would this work or is Google requiring other informations other than the response key?

---

```
# I get the response key from my local website
CaptchaKey = response-key

# I post the response key on the original website
request.post(SubmitURL, data={'g-captcha-response': CaptchaKey}
```

---

Would this work? If so, how do I check if the request has been successfully posted?

Answer (score 0):

Google captcha key won't be enough. You should consider a method with selenium+requests.

first part:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('desiredurl')
#somesleep/waittill element/anything to wait till you solve the recaptcha
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

part 2

```
session = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookies:
    session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

payload = { 'username' : '',
            'password' : '',
            'g-captcha-response': CaptchaKey}


login = session.post('DESIREDURL', data = payload)
```

This method should work